# Export data to a .csv file on ruby app

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

I got an error

```
undefined method `form_for_results_path'
```

in my code to Export the data to a .csv file. Really don't know if I missed something. Here what I have:

item_controller

```
def export
  CSV.open("result_data.csv", "w") do |csv|
    csv << ["cod", "genre", "den_cont"]
  end
end
```

In the view

```
<%= link_to 'Download CSV', form_for_results_path(@form), :method => :export %>
```

Thanks

Comment: it's saying that route doesn't exist

Comment: have u tried this ? https://gist.github.com/lmjabreu/328013

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this and read some more about rails basics.

```
 <%= link_to 'Download CSV', controller: :item, action: :export%>
```

Answer (score 2):

in your controller, you should do something like this, using rails [`send_data`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) method:

```
def export
  data = # your data in csv format
  options = {
    :filename => "some_name.csv",
    :type     => 'text/csv'
  }

  send_data(data, options)
end
```

you can also change your download link using a route_helper.  add an entry in your routes file

```
get 'items/export', :as 'download_items_data"
```

then your link_to can look like this:

```
link_to 'Download CSV', download_items_data_path
```